# Office FileDialog Interface in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I'm moving from VBA to .NET and in VBA I've used the Application.FileDialog object.  I've really liked it because you can change button names and the dialog is nice.  Anyway, so now I would like to use this in a .NET program I'm writing however because I'm a little new to .NET I don't know how to implement this.

It uses the Microsoft.Office.Core reference and whenever I try to instantiate the FileDialog it says that it can't because it's a interface. Ok I understand that but then how to I instantiate it?  I tried creating a new class and then writing "Implements FileDialog" but then VS gives me a huge list of properties and methods of the FileDialog that I need to do something with...I'm confused.  This is the reference from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Core.FileDialog%28v=office.14%29.aspx

So here are my questions:

1. How do I implement this regardless if there is a better choice?  ...I just want want to learn
2. Is there a better way? A different way?

**UPDATE:** Looking for a folder browser that looks like a file browser

thanks!
Justin

Comment: You would need to use `Application.FileDialog`, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you show the Toolbox for your form there is an `OpenFileDialog` (and others) that you can drag onto your form. There is a simple example of its use [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/let-users-pick-a-file-to-open-via-openfiledialog-in-vbnet/481).

You can use the Microsoft.Office.Core version if you prefer, but it is a bit more effort (for little gain).

**Added** the initial steps for the Office folder dialog (from VB.NET) are:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core       'Project menu, Add references
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim xl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

        xl.FileDialog(MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show()


    End Sub
End Class
```

You need to go to the Project menu, Add Reference(s) firstly. I'm using Excel but it could be Access, etc.

[Here is](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/294728-browse-folder-visual-basic-applications.html) an Excel VBA example - you can just incorporate the extra code into mine.

Comment: That's good except, even with the OpenFolderDialog, it doesn't have that textbox where you can enter in a folder's name and press enter and it opens it up...for some reason my users love that feature so I can't take it away from them. I'm really pretty much forced to use this Microsoft.Office.Core version...just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks!  This will help me a lot.  I also see this creates a new instance of Excel/Microsoft Application.  Is there anyway for that not to happen, but still use that type of dialog box?  I'm just thinking to keep things uniform when I continue expanding the application.

Comment: I believe you need to attach the dialog to an Office Application instance. This isn't a big deal as you are not doing anything with it. BTW That example I found is pretty poor, I'm sure you will find a better example.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) control

```
 System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog()
```

Does it fits your needs?

Comment: Essentially that is it but it is to pick folders.  Specifically I'm using this type msoFileDialogFolderPicker, which offers the user the ability to type in a folder name and press enter, etc. when browsing